# Spring Boot not recognizing Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface Animal {
  void setName(String animal);
  String getName();
}
```

and I have a Class that implements the interface:

```
@Component
public class Dog implements Animal {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
          this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
          return this.name;
    }
}
```

In another class (ProcessAnimal), I AutoWire the interface:

```
public class ProcessAnimal {
     @Autowired
     public Animal animal;

     public void processAnimals() {
         animal.setName("Fido");
     }
}
```

I only have one class that implements `Animal` so this should work, however, I get a `NullPointerException` when it hits the `animal.setName("Fido");` line. IntelliJ is complaining that `Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service...)` which I have... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried to add a `@Qualifier`, but still it didn't work and it shouldn't be necessary since I only have one implementation.

```
-java
    -com.example.com.AnimalProcessing
    -Animal
       -Animal.java
       -Dog.java
    -ProcessAnimal.java
    -AnimalProcessingApplication.java
```

AnimalProcessingApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AnimalProcessingApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(AnimalProcessingApplication.class, args);
           run();
     }

     public static void run() {
           ProcessAnimal processAnimal = new ProcessAnimal();
           processAnimal.processAnimals();
     }
}
```

Comment: are these classes in the same (or in a subpackage) of your main class which starts your Spring Boot application? This is required for the component scan to be able to find your beans

Comment: Please share pakage information of all these classes including Spring Boot main class.

Comment: @rieckpil I have updated my question with package information

Comment: @AnkurLathi I have updated my question with this information, please take a look

Comment: annotate `ProcessAnimal` with `@Component`  . When you are creating an instance of an object with `new` keyword , it is not a spring managed bean. For Autowiring within `ProcessAnimal` to happen correctly , `ProcessAnimal` should be a bean and the bean should be obtained from the application context.

Comment: @R.G I added the `@Component` annotation to `ProcessAnimal` but it still is giving the same error

Comment: @user2896120 You cannot use `new` keyword to create an instance. You must get the spring managed instance, so you need to get it from the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Animal Processing Application.java must be on root folder of all classes.
Then all components in child folders are recognized automatically.

Update:
Create a config class with @Bean method to create an instance with a Dog. Also then you can get rid of the @Component annotation of the class. 
The problem here is the constructor String name which cannot be injected.

Update 2:
Don't create the instances by yourself. Let spring container create them. Remove the run method.

Comment: This still isn't working for some reason. It is giving me the same null pointer error

Comment: Just saw you created the instance with new by yourself. You don't need to do that.

Comment: So I created the Config class and removed the new keyword and also the run. I am Autowiring everything. but it's still giving that error

Comment: Can you upload the code to github? It's easier to solve it, when you see the complete structure.

Answer (score 0):

**AnimalProcessingApplication** class should be one level above all other classes.

Also **you are using new for creation of object instead of using Dependency Injection** (autowiring).

Replace below -

```
ProcessAnimal processAnimal = new ProcessAnimal();
```

with

```
@Autowired
ProcessAnimal processAnimal;
```

*Also make sure that **ProcessAnimal** is a bean and **Animal** is injected in this class using autowiring.*

Comment: When you say: `class should be one level above all other classes` where exactly should it be? I put everything in a package except for the `AnimalProcessingApplication.java` class....and it is still not working

Comment: Suppose the main class is com.example.AnimalProcessingApplication then all other classess should be in package com.example.animal.*.

Comment: Also have you changed ProcessAnimal into a bean and removed the new keyword for instantiation

Comment: Yes I have, but for some reason the autowire is not working. It is still returning a null pointer

Comment: Can you please update the question with changes you made in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Following are to be done to make this program work.

1.`ProcessAnimal` should be made a component . Annotating the class with `@Component` will mark the class to be autodetected during component scan.

```
@Component
public class ProcessAnimal {
     @Autowired
     public Animal animal;

     public void processAnimals() {
         animal.setName("Fido");
     }
}
```

2. Obtain the `ProcessAnimal` class from the application context. The spring will prepare the `ProcessAnimal` bean with all its dependencies set.

You may do this in multiple ways and following is one of those

```
@Component
public class CheckRedRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    ProcessAnimal process;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        process.processAnimals();
    }

}
```

A bean implementing ApplicationRunner will be run when the application starts.

or else

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AnimalProcessingApplication.class, args);
          ProcessAnimal process = ctx.getBean(ProcessAnimal.class);
          process.processAnimals();
     }
```

Couple of observations

1. the package names by convention uses lower case letters

example : `com.example.process.entity`

2. Please go through the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) to learn the expected way of writing Spring boot application.

Comment: Hmm I see, this is working but it seems like it's getting the interface's method definitions instead of the Dog definitions. For example, one of my interface method definition is `Object getAnimalType()` and in the `Dog` class I do `Canine getAnimalType()` which `Canine is a class. When I do Canine canine = animal.getAnimalType() it is not using the Dog's definition because it gives me an error that says it's expecting an Object

Comment: I asked another question in my previous comment because it's still not working as expected

Comment: Shouldn't that be a fresh question ? Also I didnt understand the question completely. Could you please update the question with the new error if you feel that is part of the same question